# spring tool suite update error:No remedy found

Tags: spring-tool-suite, sts

try to upgrade spring tool suite to latest version,got the following error
[image: spring tool suite update No remedy found error]

my installed version

[image: install spring tool suite version]

update sites
[image]

Any idea to resolve this issue? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have the Eclipse update site for Eclipse 4.25 included and enabled (so one that points to a specific Eclipse version), but you are trying to update to the latest Spring Tools 4.18.1 release, which is not compatible anymore with that Eclipse version.

I would recommend to either update to the latest Eclipse release as well as the latest Spring Tools release, or use a version-specific update site for both (Eclipse and the Spring Tools). The Spring Tools specific update site that points to the latest release for your Eclipse 4.25 version is:

https://download.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/sts4/update/e4.25

(instead of the one that points to the latest). And disable the update site for the Spring Tools 4 Language Servers, you don't need that here.

That should - at least - give you a compatible version on those update sites. Given the list of update sites in your preferences, it also looks like you have installed a bunch of additional third-party plugins, so I can't speak to that and have no idea whether they are compatible with the latest Eclipse version or not.

The latest Spring Tools version that was compatible with Eclipse 4.25 was 4.18.0.

Comment: get the same error

Comment: can you add details about the installation problem then? The dialog with should have more details included in that section where it says "cannot complete the installation..."

Comment: I give up,reinstall sts 4.18.1.RELEASE

Comment: probably the best choice indeed